# Deploy the docker image of a client on Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, client, web-deployment, billing

A client told me to deploy a docker image for him on Cloud Run. I am able to do that in my own account. Once it is done, the problem is that it is to me to pay the maintenance fee. Do you know the best practice to avoid this problem ?
Should I tax my client every month ? Or should I deploy the docker image on the gcp account of my client ? Or is it possible to directly tax my client from my gcp account ?
Thanks in advance and sorry for this silly question.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have two choices:

- deploy in your project and pay the fees. How you manage reibursement is up to you.
- deploy in your customer's project and they pay the fees.

Best practice: deploy in their project so that they own the service and are responsible for that service, e.g. following Google Terms of Service.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. But there is another point that I would like to clarify. The gcloud CLI tool (terminal) automatically  has access to my GCP account. But if I disconnect and connect to my client account, is there something to do in order to the gcloud CLI tool (terminal) has access to the GCP account of my client? Or is it automatic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LouisDemange The CLI has config settings. You can set the project, account, region, etc. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config Then there are also configurations: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/configurations

Comment: OK if I understand well, I will need to ask to the client to create a project. Then I will need to ask the access to the project ? And then deploy the app in the project from my own google account ?

Comment: @LouisDemange Yes, the client will need to create the project and grant you access to the project. You do **not** deploy from your project. You deploy from your local system to their project. I recommend that you post new questions so that you can get better answers than what comments allow.